# Assigning string to Range.value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an odd problem. This below does not work. I get a 1004 runtime error.

```
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = some_text_generator_returning_string()
    some_range.Cells(1, 9).Value = tmp
```

If I do this

```
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = some_text_generator_returning_string()
    tmp = "foobar" & tmp
    some_range.Cells(1, 9).Value = tmp
```

It works. Why is that?

Comment: What is the value of tmp? Insert ¸Debug.Print tmp
after ¸tmp = some_text_generator_returning_string()¨. I get the error only if the range is out of bounds e.g. ¨Range(Cells(1, Columns.Count), Cells(1, Columns.Count)).Cells(1, 9).Value = tmp¨

Comment: What line errors out?